# Добавление элементов HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть список элементов. Я должен удалить первый элемент, а в конец добавить еще один. Как я это реализовал:

```
let tmp = photo_items[6].cloneNode(true);
body.insertBefore(tmp, photo_items[6]);
photo_items[6].src = imgs[k % 11 + 1].src;
k++;
photo_items[0].remove();
```

Ну и, чтобы их различать я назначаю каждому свою картинку. Так вот последний элемент перед тем, как уйти назад, сначала мигает. То есть последний элемент сначала появляется поверх предпоследнего, а потом к нему применяются (видимо) стили. Как этого избежать?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Вы наблюдаете асинхронную загрузки картинки.

```
let tmp = photo_items[6].cloneNode(true);
tmp.style.display = 'none';
body.insertBefore(tmp, photo_items[6]);
tmp.onload = function() { 
  photo_items[0].remove();
  this.style.display = '';
};
tmp.src = imgs[k % 11 + 1].src;
k++;
```

Comment: Не помогло. Проблема осталась